# REST API How to generate a 500 Error status when using a Postman Request

Tags: rest, postman, status, http-status-code-500

I need to test the 500 'internal server error' but Need to test this new API with calls from postman.  Does anyone know how to make a call that will trigger it? I'm not talking about setting up a mock or doing it from the dev side.  I need to invoke 500 responses by making requests so I can verify that a 500 request is returned from this new server.

Comment: How would anyone be able to advise you how to raise a 500 error in *your* API? Maybe there isn't a possibility at all, if you catch all exceptions and return a 400 instead?

Comment: Typically, if the implementation of the API is solid enough, a client request should not be able to reproducible provoke a 500 response

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Internal Server Error is internal to your system and you will get it when there is some issue in your code.

If the code doesn't has issues and you just want to get a 500 error status for testing then you can throw an exception like NullPointerException from your code.

Answer (score 0):

the 500 error can be get by not passing necessary parameter in header eg x-api-key and also incorrect data in request as not accepted by server eg name an be Name

Answer (score 0):

example for just one case:You can put wrong Url than response status code should be 500

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).